# Django - how to bulk delete

Tags: python, django

I'm working in a CRUD and one of the features of the list is bulk delete. The user chooses (checkbox) the lines he wants to delete and press the "Delete selected" button.

I'm using generic views in my CRUD. My single delete, for example is like this:

```
class ContentDeleteView(NextRedirectMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Content
    template_name = 'content_delete.html'    

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, "Content deleted successfully.")
        return reverse('content:content-detail')
```

My problem is creating the bulk delete view. Is there something from Django core features that I could use to bulk delete? I would like to avoid installing an app for that.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can't use `DeleteView`. It's designed for single delete. Just inherit from `View` and compose your own `get` and `post` method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views

Comment: Thanks @ShangWang ! That's what I'm doing now. I remember you answered another question of mine this morning. Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should resort to rolling out your own kind of delete view, here is a basic example:

```
class BulkDeleteView(View):
    model = None

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        delete_ids = request.POST['delete_ids'].split(',')  # should validate
        self.model.objects.filter(pk__in=delete_ids).delete()
        return render / redirect
```

So the basic idea is to subclass `View` and roll out your own implementation of a base `BulkDeleteView`

Comment: It might be better to inherit from `ListView`

Comment: @JamesFenwick if you are using the same view to display the list, I agree. I wanted to do a general case that might include handling a json request as well